# when i load my model inside gazebo by (add path) it works good,but when i export the model inside the ~/.bashrc,gazebo is freezed and nothing work

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**`wanted path`**

```
 export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/home/mahmoud/dev_ws/src/basic_mobile_robot/models/
```

same bath is worked inside gazebo!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401030/when-i-load-my-model-inside-gazebo-by-(add-path)-it-works-good,but-when-i-export-the-model-inside-the-%7E/.bashrc,gazebo-is-freezed-and-nothing-work/) by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2022-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the problem was that u need to source <gazebo_install_path>/share/gazebo/setup.sh before export the path

---

Originally posted by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) with karma: 40 on 2022-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0